# Serverless VPC is disconnected after deploying Cloud Run service from visual studio code

Tags: google-cloud-run

Our solution is built from a set of micro services that run in Cloud Run.
DB connectivity is done via Serverless VPC.

After deploying cloud run service from visual studio code the VPC configuration is set to None.
This requires running another deployment from GC ui (after selecting to VPC connector).

This has started recently (2 or 3 weeks ago).

Is there a way to get around it?

Thank you!